# SQL Tree / Hierarchial Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

This is my first post, I am trying to make a sql tree table that traverses. For example, If a person clicks on a drop down list called Categories, it will display Electric, and InterC. Then, if the user clicks on electric, it will drop down relays and switches, next if the person clicks on relays it will drop down X relays and if the person clicks on switches it will drop down Y switches. I have attempted below , but the part i don't understand is if i have another category InterC, how do I make that another level of drop downs ?

Table Category

```
insert test select 1, 0,'Electric'
insert test select 2, 1,'Relays'
insert test select 3, 1,'Switches'
insert test select 5, 2,'X Relays'
insert test select 6, 2,'Y Switches'
insert test select 7, 0,'InterC'
insert test select 8, 1,'x Sockets'
insert test select 9, 1,'y Sockets'
insert test select 10, 2,'X Relays'
insert test select 11, 2,'Y Relays'
;

create table test(id int,parentId int,name varchar(50)) 
WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name) as  (    
  SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name 
  FROM test    WHERE parentid = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1, c2.name    
  FROM test c2 
   INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM tree 
order by parentid
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hierarchical T-SQL query should return all the records in the table, both those under `Electric` and `InterC`.

However, you should make `parentId` nullable and have the root records have a `null` rather than `0`. That will let you add a foreign key that protects your data integrity (it won't be possible to add orphaned records by mistake).

You hierarchy query returns all of your records, I'm guessing that you want to return just one at a time - for that add a `where` condition to the starting query.

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name) as (    
    SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name 
    FROM test    
    WHERE name = @category AND
        parentId is null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1, c2.name    
    FROM test c2 
        INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM tree 
order by parentid
```

Then set `@category` to `'Electric'` or`'InterC'` to get one or the other hierarchy.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean set @category to electric or interc?

Comment: @turb03D `@category` is a SQL parameter: `declare @category varchar(50) = 'Electric'` to set it in SQL, but you should pass parameters using the connection object you're using to execute the SQL. This will be something like `sqlCommand.Text = "{your query}"; sqlCommand.AddParameter("category", "Electric")`.

Comment: can I set both so it can be dynamically used ?

Comment: declare ATcategory varchar(50) = 'Electric' declare &  @category varchar(50) = 'InterC'

Comment: @turb03D yeah, you'll have to tell us more about your front end technology stack of you want help with that though.

Comment: it's a basic drop down list that 
if you click on categories you get 
Electric, InterC, 
if you click electric it will drop down 
Relays and Switches
and if you click on Relays it drops down a list of relays.
if you click switches it will drop down a list of switches. 

now back to the top, if you click on InterC , it will drop down two values, then if you click on one value it will drop down another. Same as the drop down lists of Electric

Comment: @turb03D I could set up a drop down list in about 20 different technologies. Is it web? Desktop? Mobile? .Net, Java, C, something else? You'll have to tell us what tech stack you're using.

Comment: sorry , it's for Web application in C# using ASP.NET.

Comment: @turb03D ah that's not a basic drop down - you have one drop down that drives the next level down. You probably don't need the whole hierarchy retrieved from SQL as you'll be populating each level for a specific parent ID. What is messier is drawing each successive level of drop down - you'll probably need to use some AJAX for it to not be really clunky. I think you may be best off putting that in a whole other question.

Comment: thank you for your help @keith. its really hard for me to explain what you just commented. It's exactly what I'm trying to do . what keywords do you recommend to search for on google ?

Comment: @turb03D linked or cascading drop downs.